# High efficiency buck-boost converters for 3.3V and 4V power rails up to 3A peak current

Tags: power, power-electronics, components, design, buck-boost

I need a buck-boost converter to power a 3.8-4.5V GSM module and a 3.3V controller from batteries. So I need a boost-buck converter that can give me a stable voltage over the lifetime of the batteries. Normally I'd use [TPS61021ADSGR](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/TPS61021A) but it seems it's nowhere to be found - globally unavailable until November.

So I'm looking for alternatives with similar performance. Any ideas?

Comment: You should give more info on your requirements. Also it is not generally a good idea ask for which component is better since it's subjective

Comment: Input voltage will be < 5V and most of the time the current will be low (<10 uA). I could list more requirements if needed but I'm still in the design phase and I could still change things, if I have to. Anything similar to the component I mentioned should work. Note that I'm not asking for _better_ components. I'm asking for similar components, which is quite objective given their datasheets.